# Is there a way to check the instanceof my object while calling the constructor?

Tags: java

I have two constructors for my class:

```
public Foo( Bar bar, Baz baz ) {
    // do stuff
}
public Foo( Bar bar ) {
    this( bar, new Baz() );
}
```

Now, Baz has a constructor that takes a boolean. I'd like to pass the value of `this instanceof FooSubclass`. Eclipse is giving me an error saying "Cannot refer to 'this' nor 'super' while explicitly invoking a constructor"

I see an explanation of why this is happening in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625646/refering-to-this-while-invoking-super-constructor), but I'm just wondering if there's a way around it in this case.

Comment: Why? Why should a superclass ctor know about any specific subclasses? Are you trying to make a factory method instead?

Comment: That sounds like an extraordinary inappropriate coupling between types. A supertype should never even have to know its subtypes exist when compiled, which is violated when putting in an `instanceof` check in this fashion.

Comment: It's not that the super class needs to know. It's more that the Baz class needs to know if it should allow x or not. The boolean that controls the functionality is final, so I need to set it in the constructor. All the subclasses need x to be true, except one that needs it to be false. I know that I can pass it in to Foo(Bar), but I was wondering if there was a way to do it without passing it in.

Comment: @TomG I hear that. I guess I should pass it in, making that constructor `Foo(Bar bar, boolean controlsX)`

Comment: @chama Or just don't construct a `Baz` on anyone's behalf -- you already have a constructor which injects a ready Baz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can do this.

```
public Foo( Bar bar, Baz baz ) {
    // do stuff
}
public Foo( Bar bar ) {
    this( bar, new Baz() );
}
public Foo( Bar bar, boolean flag) {
    this( bar, new Baz(flag) );
}
```

Comment: That's what I ended up doing. Although I didn't really want to have to pass in a flag.
Thanks!

Comment: @chama: Technically, you don't.  You can create an instance of Baz with the flag and use the first constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Pass `null` to the main constructor, and do the check in there:

```
public Foo( Bar bar, Baz baz ) {
    if (baz == null) {
        baz = new Baz(this instanceof FooSubClass);
    }
    // do stuff
}
public Foo( Bar bar ) {
    this( bar, null );
}
```