# Cannot reference this before supertype constructor has been called

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I'm attempting to implement a circular queue class in Java. And in doing so I had to created a node class to group together elements and pointers to the next node. Being circular, the nodes need to be able to point to themselves. However when I go to compile the code below, the compiler (javac) is telling me I'm doing something wrong with my constructors (namely lines 5 and 8) giving the error of the question's namesake, and I cannot figure out why it isn't working.

Any help and explanation of why my usage is incorrect is appreciated.

```
public class Node<Key>{
    private Key key;
    private Node<Key> next;
    public Node(){
        this(null, this);
    }
    public Node(Key k){
        this(k, this);
    }
    public Node(Key k, Node<Key> node){
        key = k;
        next = node;
    }
    public boolean isEmpty(){return key == null;}
    public Key getKey(){return key;}
    public void setKey(Key k){key = k;}
    public Node<Key> getNext(){return next;}
    public void setNext(Node<Key> n){next = n;}
}
```

Comment: Have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625646/refering-to-this-while-invoking-super-constructor ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot refer tho this (or super) in a constructor, so you should change your code like this:

```
public class Node<Key>{
    private Key key;
    private Node<Key> next;
    public Node(){
    key = null;
        next = this;
    }
    public Node(final Key k){
    key = null;
        next = this;
    }
    public Node(final Key k, final Node<Key> node){
        key = k;
        next = node;
    }
    public boolean isEmpty(){return key == null;}
    public Key getKey(){return key;}
    public void setKey(final Key k){key = k;}
    public Node<Key> getNext(){return next;}
    public void setNext(final Node<Key> n){next = n;}
}
```

Comment: After reading the comments and answers, this is essentially the same code I settled on however I didn't use the keyword final (and javac didn't complain). What purpose does it serve here? And should I use it? (I think you meant "key = k" in the 9th line, but that's a sidenote)

Comment: The final keyword isn't necessary, it just tells the virtual machine to use less heap memory as possible. As for the 9th line you are right.

Answer (score 3):

The compile error is

```
Cannot refer to 'this' nor 'super' while explicitly invoking a constructor
```

Basically, you cannot use "`this`" from inside "`this(...)`"

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to pass it in all cases. since you can refer to it in the other construtor

Answer (score 0):

Can not pass "this" as a parameter to call the constructor.